# can text loaded with spry from an XML file be replaced by sIFR text?

Tags: sifr

I'm a relative newb when it comes to sIFR but I have managed to get it up an running before. I've never heard of this problem though. I have data loading via Adobe Spry into my page and then i'm trying to apply the sIFR replacement to that text once it's loaded. I can either get sIFR to replace the place holder text but then not load the text from XML OR I can load the XML data but then not have sIFR style the text at all. I can't get both to work. No idea what the problem is. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Link and username and password below. (It's only protected because the site is not finished and i don't want the Search engine spiders picking it up yet.)

jordanheider.com/builder.php

username: dash
password: kudzu

Answer (score 0):

sIFR can only replace what is both in the document at the time of replacement, and displayed on the page. So in your case, indeed after loading the new content into the page, you must do the replacements again.

I've noticed a few animations, it's possible the timing is incorrect, meaning that the content isn't actually displayed yet when you do the replacement.

Not sure what you mean by not being able to load new text if sIFR replaces the placeholder text, but it sounds like sIFR might be preventing the code responsible for loading text from firing. This could be solved by hooking up an event manually, using the `onRelease` callback you can specify in `sIFR.replace()`.

Comment: Mark, I was able to successfully get the xml content to load and then replace the text with sIFR using a regular onclick function. How can I trigger the sIFR.replace() code to fire again automatically after I know the data has loaded into the page?

Would an "onload" trigger added to the body tag do it or would that fire before the data has loaded?

Thanks for your help so far.